# Elasticsearch in Java: SearchHit fragments get shortened

Tags: java, elasticsearch, highlighting, elasticsearch-2.0

I use highlighting that is already part of Elasticsearch. It work fine. For example if I have next "words" indexed :

1. verylongwork that isweryweeylongf
2. tes!tr%31=!"$:_ae test !"daca214xx

And if I search for -> **that** .The result is as it folows -> verylongwork **that** isweryweeylongf . Including the bolding part.
But if I search for -> **test** . The result is -> $:_ae **test** !" .

So the fragment gests splited/shortened.

It probably has something to do with special characters. When searching I use QueryParser.escape() to escape them.

What could be the problem ?

EDIT:
Also if I search for **tes** the result would be two fragments -> **tes**!tr and $:_ae **tes**t !"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it would seem that the "problem" was that I had default number of fragments (5) set. In my case it makes no sense since I am searching for shorter strings.
So the solution is :

```
 final HighlightBuilder.Field field = new HighlightBuilder.Field(fieldToHighlight.getName());
        field.preTags("<strong>");
        field.postTags("</strong>");
        field.numOfFragments(0);
```

Simple as just setting numOfFragments to 0.